# I need to retrieve MongoDB's object just with filtered's array item

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm needing to retrieve just with two dates, all the documents from my MongoDB's collection, with the filtered items from the array.

This is an example of 2 of my documents;

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f18fa823406b7000132d097"),
        "last_date" : "22/07/2020 23:48:32",
        "history_dates" : [
                "22/07/2020 23:48:32",
                "22/07/2020 00:18:53",
                "23/07/2020 00:49:12",
                "23/07/2020 01:19:30"
        ],
        "hostname" : "MyHostname1",
        "ip" : "142.0.111.79",
        "component" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\es-ES\\KernelBase.dll.mui",
        "process" : "LogonUI.exe",
        "date" : "23/07/2020 10:26:04",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f18fa823406b7000132d098"),
        "last_date" : "22/07/2020 23:48:33",
        "history_dates" : [
                "22/07/2020 23:48:33",
                "23/07/2020 00:18:53",
        ],
        "hostname" : "MyHostName2",
        "ip" : "142.0.111.54",
        "component" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\es-ES\\KernelBase.dll.mui",
        "process" : "svchost.exe",
        "date" : "23/07/2020 10:26:04",
}
```

I'm needing to make a find to my database (Using Spring Data), to retrieve the same objects, but with the  "history_dates"'s array filtered between the 2 dates recieved.

For example, if my 2 recieved dates are: "23/07/2020" and "24/07/2020", I want MongoDB to return the next objects;

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f18fa823406b7000132d097"),
        "last_date" : "22/07/2020 23:48:32",
        "history_dates" : [
                "23/07/2020 00:49:12",
                "23/07/2020 01:19:30"
        ],
        "hostname" : "MyHostname1",
        "ip" : "142.0.111.79",
        "component" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\es-ES\\KernelBase.dll.mui",
        "process" : "LogonUI.exe",
        "date" : "23/07/2020 10:26:04",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f18fa823406b7000132d098"),
        "last_date" : "22/07/2020 23:48:33",
        "history_dates" : [
                "23/07/2020 00:18:53"
        ],
        "hostname" : "MyHostName2",
        "ip" : "142.0.111.54",
        "component" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\es-ES\\KernelBase.dll.mui",
        "process" : "svchost.exe",
        "date" : "23/07/2020 10:26:04",
}
```

I'm really ignorant about MongoDB's queries, and I have been trying to make this with Spring Data all the week.

UPDATE 1.

Thanks varman, and do you know how can i just retrieve the documents with filtered arrays not empty?

Comment: Do you have any codes that you implemented?

Comment: I've been trying using MongoCollection, but I can't make it work, im really in blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need to do filter. `MongoTemplate` offers a lot of operation for mongodb, if some methods don't exist in MongoTemplate, we can go with Bson `Document` pattern. In that case, try this article: [Trick to covert mongo shell query](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/).

Actually you need a Mongo query something like following. Using `$addFields` one of the methods shown below. But you can use `$project`, `$set` etc. Here `$addFields` overwrites your `history_dates`. (It uses to add new fields to document too).

```
{
    $addFields: {
        history_dates: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$history_dates",
                cond: {
                    $and: [{
                            $gt: ["$$this", "23/07/2020"]
                        },
                        {
                            $lt: ["$$this", "24/07/2020"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NPUMnYMpp6a).

You need to convert this into spring data. So `@Autowired` the MongoTemplate in you class.

```
 @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

The method is,

```
public List<Object> filterDates(){

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        a->new Document("$addFields",
            new Document("history_dates",
                new Document("$filter",
                    new Document("input","$history_dates")
                    .append("cond",
                        new Document("$and",
                            Arrays.asList(
                                new Document("$gt",Arrays.asList("$$this","23/07/2020")),
                                new Document("$lt",Arrays.asList("$$this","24/07/2020"))                            
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )       
        )
    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_CLASS.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Mongo template doesn't provide add methods for `$addFields` and `$filter`. So we just go with bson document pattern. I haven't tested this in Spring.

Comment: Yes!!!! Really thanks for the code snippet and the explanation! Do you know if there is a way to not retrieve the objects with empty filtered array?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of ways, if the questeion is related to this, just update the question with any indicator like "UPDATE 1", else open another question and add th url here.

Comment: Hahaah, Just post a sample, i dont understand wt you mentioned "filtered array not empty"

Comment: Do you need to omit the documents which has empty history_dates?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that.

Comment: use `$match`. Play grpund https://mongoplayground.net/p/dU3M_l0dYoL  and in java, `match(Criterial.where("history_dates").ne(Arrays.asList()))`  after the `$$addFields`