# How to retrieve data from MongoDB using Spring - group by latest datetime for each day?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents in the below format in MongoDB. I want to extract the data grouped by category, name, date (in the format like yyyy-mm-dd) by latest creationDatetime for each day to know the status either passed or failed.

```
{ "name":"Scenario number one", "category":"general", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-15T00:18:35.608+00:00", "status":"Passed" },
{ "name":"Scenario number one", "category":"general", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-15T00:11:35.608+00:00", "status":"Failed" },
{ "name":"Scenario number one", "category":"general", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-15T00:08:35.608+00:00", "status":"Passed" },
{ "name":"Scenario number two", "category":"happy-path", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-15T00:17:35.608+00:00", "status":"Failed" },
{ "name":"Scenario number one", "category":"general", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-13T00:12:35.608+00:00", "status":"Passed" },
{ "name":"Scenario number two", "category":"happy-path", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-12T00:11:35.608+00:00", "status":"Failed" },
{ "name":"Scenario number two", "category":"happy-path", "creationDateTime":"2020-06-12T00:10:35.608+00:00", "status":"Passed" }
```

I want output in the format like

```
{"category":"general", "name":"Scenario number one", "date":"2020-06-15", "status":"Passed"}
{"category":"happy-path", "name":"Scenario number two", "date":"2020-06-15", "status":"Failed"}
{"category":"general", "name":"Scenario number one", "date":"2020-06-13", "status":"Failed"}
{"category":"happy-path", "name":"Scenario number two", "date":"2020-06-12", "status":"Failed"}
```

Please help with Spring Code. Thank you!

Comment: Grouping is not filtering. Grouping by day means using all of the documents for each day.

Comment: Sort by timestamp, convert timestamp to date, group by date, use $last to get the most recent document for each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mongo query is like

```
[
  {
    $sort: {
      "creationDateTime": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {
        "$substr": [
          "$creationDateTime",
          0,
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        name: "$name",
        cat: "$category",
        cdt: "$date"
      },
      "category": {
        $first: "$category"
      },
      status: {
        $first: "$status"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      date: {
        $first: "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TI4V1Qa6owf). And the aggregation in Spring,

```
 public List<Object> test() {
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "creationDateTime"),
                a -> new Document("$addFields",
                        new Document("date",
                                new Document("$substr", Arrays.asList("$creationDateTime", 0, 10))
                        )
                ),
                group(Fields.from(
                        Fields.field("name", "$name"),
                        Fields.field("category", "$category"),
                        Fields.field("date", "$date")
                ))
                        .first("category").as("category")
                        .first("status").as("status")
                        .first("name").as("name")
                        .first("date").as("date"),
                project().andExclude("_id")

        ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

    }
```

I didn't test it, but it should work, and [see this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066314/i-need-to-retrieve-mongodbs-object-just-with-filtereds-array-item/63077218#63077218).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have the timestamp stored in ISO format. I would need the timestamp converted to CST with daylight savings before extracting from the timestamp. Would that be possible to do? The reason is that the actual dateTime of the record inserted is at CST. Due to which the results are not accurate when retrieving based on ISO date only.

Comment: That might be possible,  i haven't tried. Ref https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/ . If you dont find anything useful in searching, open a question

Comment: I used context -> new Document("$addFields", new Document("date", DateOperators.DateToString.dateOf("creationDateTime").toString("%m-%d-%Y").toDocument(context)))  instead of context -> new Document("$addFields", new Document("date", new Document("$substr", Arrays.asList("$creationDateTime", 0, 10))))