# Mongo aggregate sum of two Strings

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am trying to sum one field in Mongo. If it is an Integer there is no issue, but the problem is that it is String and I get 0 for totalAmount

```
private Integer findRequestAmount(String agentId, String status, Date date, String amountField) {
        Aggregation aggregationAmount = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(
                        Criteria.where("rawRequest.agentId").is(agentId)
                                .and("status").is(status)
                                .and("dateCreated").gte(date)),
                Aggregation.group("rawRequest.agentId")
                        .sum(amountField).as("amount"),
                Aggregation.project().andExclude("_id"));
        HashMap results = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(aggregationAmount, "underwritingRequest", HashMap.class)
                .getUniqueMappedResult();
        return results == null ? 0 : (Integer)results.get("totalAmount");
    }
```

amountField is a String, how can I sum it in this implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `String amountField`. Simply you can convert this String to Integer by using `int x=Integer.parseInt(s)` over the aggregation and use it inside the aggregation.

Comment: The amountField is a String reference to the field in mongoDb which looks like rawRequest.amount. If the field itself in Mongo is Integer this code works, but in my case this field is String.

Comment: Then why don't you use `$toInt` pipeline to convert mongodb String field to Int to get sum.

Comment: I will research how to use this in the aggregation statements, looks like this is the way

Comment: Of course, you can, and refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066314/i-need-to-retrieve-mongodbs-object-just-with-filtereds-array-item/63077218#63077218 this too for your easiness

Comment: After investigation I found out that I can do this within the mongo logic, but with spring data I am still not able to find solution

Comment: Of couse as I said, if u feel struggling in it, please post, i will try my best to sort it out

Comment: @GeorgiMichev why don't you consider to accept the answer if this helps you.!

Comment: @GeorgiMichev how did you convert your code to raw mongo query langauge inside java? I cant get this working either :(

Comment: @kris it was 11 months ago I dont really remember. But I dont think i converted anything. I wrote all this from scratch. Looks like a repository method