# Is there any in-built function in spring mongo which can be used to extract data from two different documents having onetoone relationship?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, entity-relationship, spring-mongodb

I am just looking for extracting data from two different documents in mongodb having onetoone relationship using Mongo Template in spring.

I have two documents "Rosters" (Embedded Document belonging to User) and "Unread" both are identified by "ucid" an acronym for "unique conversation identifier". On the basis of ucid i'd like to perform inner-join operation and extract the data.
There are ample examples where lookup and aggregations are used for OneToMany Relationship but not for OnetToOne.

Following are the class

```
**User**
class User
{
private List<Roster> rosterList;
}


**Roster**

public class Roster extends Parent
{
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    @Indexed
    private String author;
@Unique
private String ucid;
 
}

**Unread**
public class
{
   @Id
    @Indexed(unique=true) //todo: create index on mongo side as well
    private String ucid;
private Map<String,Long> memberAndCount;

}


----------------------------------------------------
Sample Data:
USER (roster)
{user:{id:1001, username: dilag,roster:
[{
ucid:r0s122,name:sam}
},{
ucid:r0s123,name:ram}
},{
ucid:r0s124,name:rat}
}]}

UNREAD
{
ucid:r0s122,usernameAndCount:[{username:dilag,count:100},{username:ramg,count:20}],
ucid:r0s123,usernameAndCount:[{username:dilag,count:100},{username:ramg,count:20}]
}

Desired Output
{
ucid:r0s122, name :sam,usernameAndCount:[{username:dilag,count:100},{username:ramg,count:20}],
ucid:r0s123,name:ram,usernameAndCount:[{username:dilag,count:100},{username:ramg,count:20}]
}
```

Comment: Did you refer `@DBRef` https://www.baeldung.com/cascading-with-dbref-and-lifecycle-events-in-spring-data-mongodb ? You can do it with aggregation also

Comment: Went through it, but it doesn't solve the problem given above. FYI I am aware of @DBRef and its implications. Do you have any other links to suggest?

Comment: Yes, its has some implications. So whay dont you qoth aggregation. To join to tables we use `$lookup`. Please post some sample data and expected output, so tht we can help you

Comment: I have updated post with sample data, can you have a quick look

Comment: Please format your sample data. I feel, the format is wrong.

Comment: its formatted now @varman

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fs3o9NE5taN this is your expected result, no?

Comment: yup that is the expected result ,Do you have any idea on how to replicate it using spring mongo

Comment: Yes, give me some time. Im out of home

Answer (score 1):

The following spring code is not tested, But it's written based on working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JQTo7uXkAsi).

Basically you need to know about joining in Mongodb using `$lookup`. Here I have used [Joining Uncorrelated Sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

```
public List<Object> test() {
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        l-> new Document("$lookup",
                new Document("from","user")
                .append("let", new Document("uid","$uicd"))
                .append("pipeline",
                    Arrays.asList(
                        new Document("$unwind", "$user.roster"),
                        new Document("$match",
                            new Document("$expr",
                                new Document("$eq",Arrays.asList("$user.roster.ucid","$$uid"))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ).append("as","users")
        ),
        a-> new Document("$addFields",
                new Document("name",
                    new Document("$ifNull",
                        Arrays.asList(
                            new Document("$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("$users.user.roster.name",0))
                        ,
                        ""
                        )
                    )
                )
        )

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Unread.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066314/i-need-to-retrieve-mongodbs-object-just-with-filtereds-array-item/63077218#63077218) to understand the trick how to do aggregation if mongo spring-data doesn't provide any operation using `new Document()`.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but there is the repetition  of new Document (causing memory overhead). Can we use AggregateOperation? Anyway thanks.

Comment: Since there is no operation provided by spring data (Eg : `$addFields`, `$lookup for uncorrelated sub queries`, few places of `$project`), we need to use this way. But I hope it won't affect the performance

Comment: Excellent, this is awesome. It helped me